# Changing Radiobutton selected in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I have a gridview Template field in which there are 3 radio buttons. Once is checked and other 2 are disabled. Now the problem is if one radio button is checked and a button is clicked next time that radio button must be disabled and another radio button must be enabled for that particular row. Could you please help in this ?

```
foreach (GridViewRow gr in all_day_non_prod_GridView.Rows)
        {

            check1 = ((RadioButton)gr.FindControl("first")).Checked;
            check2 = ((RadioButton)gr.FindControl("reminder")).Checked;
            check3 = ((RadioButton)gr.FindControl("completed")).Checked;
            if (check1)
            {
                reminder = "First";
                n = 1;
                break;
            }
            else if (check2)
            {
                reminder = "Second";
                n = 2;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                reminder = "Completed";
                n = 3;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think you will want to use CheckedChanged event with your check box. This is how I use mine in one of my applications.

```
protected void cbFirstCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this helps you find the row and control in the gridview
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;
    CheckBox firstCheckBox = ((CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("cbSecondCheckBox"));
    CheckBox secondCheckBox = ((CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("cbSecondCheckBox"));

    //I believe you said you want to disable one then enable the 2nd one. 
    firstCheckBox.Enabled = false;
    secondCheckBox.Enabled = true;

}
```

Then in your HTML you want to put this.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbFirstCheckBox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="cbRemoveActive_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Enabled="false"/>
```

So now, once you click the first check box, the 2nd checkbox will be enabled and the first checkbox will be disabled. You set the AutoPostBack to true so the page refreshes. I believe this is what you are wanting. You will be able to use this technique to do the other checkboxes as well. I hope this helps.

EDIT: I just saw that you used radio buttons. You should still be able to do the same just substituting CheckBox for RadioButton's. I have not tested the above but I think it will lead you in the right direction.

Another Edit: You may be able to actually keep the foreach loop you have. That should also work.

```
protected void rbFirstButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gr in all_day_non_prod_GridView.Rows)
    {
        RadioButton rbFirstButton = ((RadioButton)gv.FindControl("rbFirstButton"));
        RadioButton rbSecondButton = ((RadioButton)gv.FindControl("rbSecondButton"));

        rbFirstButton.Enabled = false;
        rbSecondButton.Enabled = true;

    }
 }
```

Last Edit: You can't have the foreach, it will enable all the checkboxes, not only on the row you want.. the code below is what I have tested and it works.

```
    protected void rbOne_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;
        RadioButton rbOne = ((RadioButton)gvr.FindControl("rbOne"));
        RadioButton rbTwo = ((RadioButton)gvr.FindControl("rbTwo"));
        RadioButton rbThree = ((RadioButton)gvr.FindControl("rbThree"));

        rbOne.Enabled = false;
        rbTwo.Enabled = true;
        rbThree.Enabled = true;
    }
```

I believe that this is what you're looking for. I hope this helps.

Comment: can we have chat i think you have not understood what i meant. your answer helps me 50% only.

Comment: Looks like I did misunderstand you. You click a button, then it disables. Do you have the code for your button click? The code within the CheckedChanged will work for a button click as well. Just to make things clear, you select a radio button, then click a button, it then disables previously clicked radio button and enables the other two?